# Epimorphism of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find values of parameter t for which transformation is epimorphic:
$\psi([x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4])=[x_1+x_2+x_3+2x_4,x_1+tx_2+x_3+3x_4,2x_1+x_2+tx_3+3x_4] $
When this transformation is epimorphic i.e. what should i look for in the reduced form of matrix of this linear transformation?

Comment: You should write up your definition of epimorphism first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row-reduced form of the matrix must have 3 independent rows (i.e., all 3 rows must end up with "leading 1s" in them -- no rows of all zeroes).

Why? Because row-rank (= number of indep't rows) = column rank, and for the transformation to be an epimorphism, you need column rank (which is the dimension of the image) to be 3.

Comment: So to make evrything clear this transformation is an epiomorphism for $t\ne 1$? Right?

Comment: Nope. The problem occurs at a different value of $t$. Why not show us a sequence of matrices row-equivalent to the original, but simpler and simpler, so we can check your work? (Alternatively, you could use column-equivalence, if that seems easier...which it does, at least to me.)

Comment: My rref matrix is: \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
 0 & t-1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 0 & -1 & t-2 & -1
\end{pmatrix} thus i must have three independent rows thus the one with t-1 needs to be zero. So maybe it is an epimorhpism for t=1? That's all?

Comment: That's not row-reduced! Swap 2nd and 3rd rows to get $$\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\  0 & -1 & t-2 & -1 \\0 & t-1 & 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$$ and add $(t-1)$ times the second row to the third to clear the (3, 2) entry. What do you get? For what values of $t$ does the resulting row-reduced matrix have only two independent rows?

Comment: thus i have $\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\  0 & -1 & t-2 & -1 \\0 & 0 & t^2-3t+2 & -t+2  \end{pmatrix}$ thus t=2 and then it is epimorphic? but previously you wrote thata 3 independent rows are needed, i am lost

Comment: It's an epimorphism when you have three independent rows. Clearly the first two are independent regardless of $t$; for the third to be dependent, it must be all zero. Its entries are $(t-2)(t-1)$ and $2 - t$. The first is zero when $t = 1, 2$; the second is zero when $t = 2$. Hence the whole row is zero when $t = 2$...so the transformation is NOT an epimorphism when $t = 2$, but IS an epimorphism for any other value of $t$.

Comment: got it! thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
Epimorphisms must satisfy

- $\phi$ is linear (this is the case for all $t$, since $\phi$ can be represented by a matrix-vector multiplication)
- $\phi$ is surjective (that means that $\phi(\mathbb R^4) = \mathbb R^3$, i.e. $\mathrm{rank}(\phi) = 3$)

So you must check whether the matrix
$$[\psi] = \pmatrix{1&1&1&2\\1&t&1&3\\2&1&t&3}$$
Has rank $3$ (in general: full row rank). This is the case iff the REF of $[\phi]$ has the form
$$[\psi] \sim \pmatrix{1&0&0&\ast\\0&1&0&\ast\\0&0&1&\ast}$$
(in general: $[\psi]\sim\pmatrix{I_n &\ast}$ where $n$ is the number of rows)